# Why Jersey client does not handle redirects for HTTP POST requests?

Tags: jersey

I have configured Jersey client to automatically follow HTTP 302 redirects:

```
DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig config = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
config.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, true);
Client client = ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
```

This works perfectly fine when I receive HTTP 302 for HTTP GET request: the client redirects me automatically and the last response I got from client is HTTP 202.

However, when submitting HTTP POST request that results in HTTP 302, the client does not redirects me automatically. I.e., the last response from the client is HTTP 302 and I need to follow redirects manually. This behavior seems counter-intuitive for me, as Web browsers are handling such redirects automatically. The use case also seems quite common, for instance, when trying to login with HTTP POST, you often get redirected to a new page.

Why is it so? And is there a way to handle it automatically, in a same way Web browser does it?